# Construct array using each index of another array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need a little help with this as it's making my brain hurt.

Here is a string I have:

`var path = "/great-grand-parent/grand-parent/parent/";`

And an array from that:

```
var pathsArray = path.split("/");
```

After splitting that string on "/" into an array so each level stands on its own, I would like to build another array where each index of pathsArray[] is used to construct an array that would contain full paths of all parents:

0: /great-grand-parent/grand-parent/parent/

1: /great-grand-parent/grand-parent/

2: /great-grand-parent/

3: /

I tried using a for loop to loop backwards through pathsArray[] but then got confused on how to reference each index recursively.  Any help would be greatly appreciated! Probably pretty simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = pathsArray.map(function(s, i, arr) {
    return arr.slice(0, arr.length-i).join("/") || "/";
});
```

```js
var path = "/great-grand-parent/grand-parent/parent/";
var pathsArray = path.split("/");
var result = pathsArray.map(function(s, i, arr) {
    return arr.slice(0, arr.length-i).join("/") || "/";
});
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(result, null, 2) + "</pre>";
```

There's an extra result because of the trailing `/`. You can trim that away if you want.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much for your help. Pretty efficient way to do it.